# Keep Future objects around between requests?

Tags: asynchronous, jboss, ejb, wicket, ejb-3.1

I want to use the JBoss 5.1 asynch feature as described in https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html - however, I'm a bit unclear on how to keep the returned `Future` around between requests. Since it's not serializable, I can't properly keep it stored in my Wicket page nor in the http session. How do you properly handle a `Future` if you need to wait for longer than a request?

Comment: Come to think of it, I'd probably face the same problem using EJB3.1's async feature. I must be missing something here. How do you deal in general with a Future that takes longer than you can immediately wait?

Comment: Does this thread help you a little bit?
http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Handling-futures-td3688341.html

Comment: Yes it does, thanks. I guess I will keep the references in Application scope.

Comment: This question is basically answered - if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread contains a discussion about how to handle `Future` instances in Wicket:

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Handling-futures-td3688341.html